# PHP code working for theme not applicable when moved to plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, customization

i am new and just started some work with php code. I am bulding sidebar structures which should be added to pages via widget, and i use plugin to add custom widget. At the beginning, the code i put here worked when passed in footer, header or anything belongs to the theme. But when i moved it to my custom plugin, it showed a different result:

```
if(have_posts()) { 
$Cate = get_queried_object();
$related = get_posts( array( 
'category__in' => $Cate->term_id, 
'numberposts' => 8, ) );                        
if( $related ) echo '  <p>Posts in the same category:</p>';  
foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post); 
?><li> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php   ;}wp_reset_postdata()}
```

Result at the beginning:

> ### Posts in the same category:
>
> - Transportation market description
> - Our competitors
> - General introduction of transportation

Result after moved to custom plugin

> ### Posts in the same category:
>
> - Transportation market description
> - Transportation market description
> - Transportation market description

Those 3 are posts of the current category. When i echo "var_dump($post)" in foreach loop, it showed the correct information of $post at that time.

This is my plugin 's content (main content only)

```
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
 
// This is where you run the code and display the output
if(have_posts()) { 
$Cate = get_queried_object();
$related = get_posts( array( 
'category__in' => $Cate->term_id, 
'numberposts' => 8, ) );                        
if( $related ) echo '  <p>Posts in the same category:</p>';  foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post); 
?><li> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php   ;wp_reset_postdata();}};
echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```